# Angular 2: ChangeDetection and mousemove event

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular2-changedetection

I have an Angular 2 Component with many children.
Because of performance issues, I wanted to check how often the `ChangeDetection` checks my child-components. So I logged the `ngAfterViewChecked`-callback of one of my child-components.

I realized that my parent-component has a `mousemove()`-callback and so my childrens `ngAfterViewChecked` gets called every time I move my mouse over the parent. But I'm not updating any component variables in my `mousemove()`-callback. Why is the `ChangeDetection` running for the children then and how can I stop this?

I hope you understand the problem (if not please comment, so I can clarify things).

Comment: [This article is for you](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html)

Comment: thx so much, exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: Same for me, content where the mousemoves cause rerendering contains a Highcharts graphics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The site peeskillet provided shows how to exclude eventlistener from ChangeDetection:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
...
  element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  mouseDown(event) {
  ...
    this.element = event.target;

    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this));
    });
  }

  mouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.element.setAttribute('x', event.clientX + this.clientX + 'px');
    this.element.setAttribute('y', event.clientX + this.clientY + 'px');
  }
}
```

For further information I can really recommend this [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html). Big THX to peeskillet!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to put `zone.runOutsideAngular(..` inside the event handler. This helped me solve the problem at hand.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do inside your event listener. Not all use-cases need a separate zone. But glad it works for you.